# If this sequence of paths tend to a certain path $\gamma$, does the integrals along those paths tend to the integral along $\gamma$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am not sure if this result is "obvious". For example, consider the paths $\gamma_y (x)= x+iy$ for x between 0 and R, and a y. Now let $f(z)$ be a continous function. Then $\int_{\gamma_{y}}f(z) dz\rightarrow \int_{\gamma_{0}}f(z)$ as $y \rightarrow 0$? If this is not immediately evident, how can I prove it?

Comment: I would say you need your sequence of paths to uniformly converge to $\gamma_0$. If you can ensure uniform convergence, you can also ensure the convergence of the integral.

Comment: @Zanzag And how can I show that uniform convergence suffices for the integral to converge?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{ \gamma_n \}$ converges uniformly to $\gamma_0$. Suppose also that each $\gamma_n$ is $C^1$ and its derivative converges uniformly to some function $g$ and $f$ is continuous. It is a classical result then that $\gamma_0$ is differentiable and its derivative is $\gamma_0’ = g$

Then $f$ is bounded on the trace of $\gamma_n$ and $f(\gamma_n) \gamma_n’ $ converges uniformly to $f(\gamma_0) \gamma_0’$. Therefore  $\int^z_0 f(\gamma_n) \gamma_n’$ converges uniformly to $\int^z_0 f(\gamma_0) \gamma_0’ $, which is the result you are looking for.